# Вызвать объект SlidingMenu

Tags: java, android, activity

Я использую `SlidingMenu` библиотеку, и я хочу весь код, который создает `sliding menu` вынести в другой активити, чтоб, когда мне нужно было, я создавал объект и вызывал меню. Но у меня не получается так сделать.

**MainActivity**

```
final Context context = this;
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            new SlideMenu(context);

    }
```

**SlideMenu**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     }

     public SlideMenu(Context context) {
         SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(context);

         menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
         menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
         menu.setShadowWidth(15);
         menu.setFadeDegree(0.0f);
         menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
         menu.setBehindWidth(400);
         menu.setMenu(R.layout.sidemenu);
}
```

**Ошибки:**

```
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bonsite.Shkaf/com.bonsite.Shkaf.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:132)
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:65)
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.attachToActivity(SlidingMenu.java:310)
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.attachToActivity(SlidingMenu.java:292)
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at service.SlideMenu.<init>(SlideMenu.java:35)
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at com.bonsite.Shkaf.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:73)
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479)
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
05-25 20:54:30.158: E/AndroidRuntime(20274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
```

Comment: Вы хотите повторно использовать код? И вы написали активити(`SlideMenu`), вставили код в конструктор и там где вам нужно создаете эту активити(`new SlideMenu()`), что бы получить экземпляр `SlidingMenu`? Если так то вам не не нужно класс `SlideMenu` наследовать от `Activity`.

Comment: опа, говнокод. В классе SlideMenu создается экземпляр класса SlidingMenu. А еще очень радует final Context context = this; Раскройте мне секрет, в чем же вообще смысл этой строчки? Это какое-то вуду-программирование?

Comment: @katso спасибо за совет, понял ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что получилось в итоге

```
public class SlideMenu {

    Context context;

    public SlideMenu(final Context context) {

        Log.e("context ", context.toString());

        this.context = context;

        SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(context);

        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidth(15);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.0f);
        menu.attachToActivity((Activity) context, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
        menu.setBehindWidth(400);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.sidemenu);


        String[] items = {"Новости","События", "Наше меню", "Фотографии", "Видеозаписи", "Контакты", "Мой профиль"};
        ((ListView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.sidemenulistobject)).setAdapter(
                new ArrayAdapter<Object>(
                        context,
                        R.layout.sidemenu_item,
                        R.id.text,
                        items
                )
        );

        ((ListView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.sidemenulistobject)).setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch(position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent iNews = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        context.startActivity(iNews);
                    break;

                    case 1:
                        //Intent iProducts = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OurMenu.class);
                        //startActivity(iProducts);
                    break;

                    case 2:
                        Intent iProducts = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), OurMenu.class);
                        context.startActivity(iProducts);
                    break;

                    case 3:
                        //Intent iVideo = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Video.class);
                        //startActivity(iVideo);
                    break;

                    case 4:
                        Intent iGde = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), VideoMenu.class);
                        context.startActivity(iGde);
                    break;

                    case 5:
                        //Intent iContacts = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Contacts.class);
                        //startActivity(iContacts);
                    break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Унаследуйтесь от SlidingMenu